# Generalized reduced gradient nonlinear solver in Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I saw a few posts before regarding the Excel solver, but I have been unable to find a clear answer as to how to implement the GRG nonlinear solver in python (also with the option to apply constraints). Is this possible? IF so, could somebody please let me know how to achieve this, possibly with an example?